# What is the difference between ESSBASE and ESSBASE server?

Tags: essbase

What is the difference between essbase and essbase server in layman,s term?
I am not able to understand the difference, neither can i find it on internet.
Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference you are encountering likely has to do with the context in which someone refers to Essbase. To try and answer your question, though: Essbase Server tends to refers the physical computer that contains one or more Essbase databases. When one says they are "using Essbase" this might mean that they are performing an operation on their computer that is specifically communicating with the Essbase Server. This would commonly be the Essbase Excel Add-In, Smart View, or some other software.

A person using Essbase will typically do so from an Excel spreadsheet. In this case, they might be populating data in various cells by performing retrieves, pivots, and other operations until they get the desired data on their spreadsheet, and where the data is being transmitted in real time from the Essbase server.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you also help me in explaining the 3 tier architecture that is given in ESSBASE dbag in layman term? Figure number 1 on page 50 of dbag.

Comment: The three tier architecture generally refers to the fact that you have a user, an analytic provider server, and the Essbase server. This means from a technical perspective, the user is not connecting directly to the Essbase server, but rather, they connect to an intermediary server, and that server in turn communicates with the Essbase server. Originally it was just a two tier architecture where the user would connect directly to the Essbase server, but there are some advantages to having a "server in the middle".

Comment: Can you please tell me some good source to learn Hyperion planning?